# Why Can't "Bounties" be Awarded To a Question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I understand that bounties are mostly used to attract better answers but one of the reasons to award a bounty to an answer, as recognized by the PSE, is to reward an existing beautiful answer. I wonder that if a beautiful answer is accepted as an appropriate reason to reward the user with some points then why should a beautiful question not be accepted as an appropriate reason to do the same. I understand that this might be an SE-wide policy. But I would like to know what the PSE community thinks about this and then maybe the question can be moved to the SE meta if it gets a positive response.

Comment: See e.g. [this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135469/bounty-like-facility-for-rewarding-excellent-questions) on the same topic